# I want to get what I have saved in the Query database and convert it into an array. Using php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to get what I have saved in the Query database and convert it into an array. And I want to pass data to the variables that I have passed. Using php

How can I turn a **string** below into an **array**?

```
"UserID=$api_username&Token=$api_token&Account=$number&Amount=$amount&SPKey=$op&APIRequestID=$ref_id&Optional1={Optional1}&Optional2={Optional2}&Optional3={Optional3}&Optional4={Optional4}&GEOCode=[18.273827, 73.879353]&CustomerNumber=1234567890&Pincode=123456&Format=1"
```

This is the **array** I am looking for,

```
    array(
        "UserID" => $api_username,
        "Token" => $api_token,
        "Account" => $number,
        "Amount" => $amount,
        "SPKey" => $op,
        "APIRequestID" => $ref_id,
        "Optional1" => "{Optional1}",
        "Optional2" => "{Optional2}",
        "Optional3" => "{Optional3}",
        "Optional4" => "{Optional4}",
        "GEOCode" => "[18.273827, 73.879353]",
        "CustomerNumber" => "1234567890",
        "Pincode" => "123456",
        "Format" => "1"
    )
```

I used php parse_url() function but I get such an array.

```
    [
      "UserID" => "$api_username"
      "Token" => "$api_token"
      "Account" => "$number"
      "Amount" => "$amount"
      "SPKey" => "$op"
      "APIRequestID" => "$ref_id"
      "Optional1" => "{Optional1}"
      "Optional2" => "{Optional2}"
      "Optional3" => "{Optional3}"
      "Optional4" => "{Optional4}"
      "GEOCode" => "[18.273827, 73.879353]"
      "CustomerNumber" => "1234567890"
      "Pincode" => "123456"
      "Format" => "1"
    ]
```

But I should be **Comma Separated**.

Comment: That's just the way `print_r()` shows arrays. It doesn't put commas between the elements.

Comment: Commas are part of the input syntax for arrays, they're not part of the array data itself. `parse_url()` is doing the right thing.